# Getting the textview of the TabLayout's tab

Tags: android, tabs, material-design, android-tablayout

I want to programmatically change a tab's textview. Is there any way to do this?

There are answers only concerning the old TabHost view, I am using the TabLayout used by Google's Material Design library using `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.`

For TabHost:
[How to add padding to a tabs label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421564/how-to-add-padding-to-a-tabs-label)

Comment: *comic book guy's voice* "Worst, question, everrr".  Just kidding, but read how to write a good question here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  In the future you should include code, a detailed description, and what you have tried already.

Comment: It's quite hard to supply code in this context, and what I have tried is the answer below, just sharing because getting this answer is especially tricky.

Detailed description however...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a given tab:

```
 int wantedTabIndex = 0;
 TextView tv = (TextView)(((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)mTabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(wantedTabIndex)).getChildAt(0));
 tv.setText("Hello world!");
```

Comment: This crashes with `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView` in support lib `22.2.1`

Comment: I am also running 22.2.1 via "compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'", let me know with some code... Hopefully I can help you

Comment: can you elaborate on that? getting same exception. the code already looks shite. lol

Comment: this is not a safe way to go. android team can anytime update the view group hierarchy which will crash the app after updating the support libraries

Answer (score 19):

This is working solution

```
int wantedTabIndex = 0;
TextView tv = (TextView)(((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)mTabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(wantedTabIndex)).getChildAt(1));
tv.setText("Hello world!");
```

Just change the last index  **Zero** to **One** now above code will work

Removed Crash

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

Comment: what does the 1 signify. for example i have 2 tabs. want to update text style on both.???

Comment: Each tab is a LinearLayout. So your LinearLayout has 2 tabs/views. Inside of each tab, the TextView is index 1.

Answer (score 6):

```
    public static void setTextViewsCapsOff(View view) {
        if (!(view instanceof ViewGroup)) {
            return;
        }
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)view;
        for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = group.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView)child).setAllCaps(false);
            } else {
                setTextViewsCapsOff(child);
            }
        }
    }
```

Pass in your TabLayout to this recursive method. It will find any child that is a TextView and set its All Caps mode off. Avoids all the other very specific typecasting. If it does not appear to work call it later in your code. I had it in onCreate but that did not work. Called it later in code and it worked perfectly.

Affects all Tabs, not just one but I figure this is the most common usage. Not specific to TabLayout either. Can be used for any layout that contains TextViews you want to change.

Comment: This is a much cleaner and more future-proof solution than the accepted one 

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("some text");
```

Replace `0` with the index of the tab you want to edit. I think your tabLayout needs to be populated before calling this, otherwise `tablayout.getTabAt(0)` will return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do here is create a custom layout with a TextView  and then assign the custom view to the tabs you want to edit

```
final TabLayout.Tab tabAt = tabLayout.getTabAt(index);
tabAt.setCustomView(myLayoutId);
```

In this way you can do whatever you want with the TextView that is inside the layout

Comment: `tabLayout.getTabAt(index);` returns **null** value as my tab layout initially  empty

Answer (score 0):

Add ***onTabSelectedListener*** to your tabLayout to set text dynamically.
so in this approach when tab will be selected text will become "selected" or other tab

```
 tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.getCustomView().setAlpha(1.0f);
            ((TextView) tab.getCustomView()).setTextSize(12);
            ((TextView) tab.getCustomView()).setText("Selected");
            Log.d("TabBar", "selected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.getCustomView().setAlpha(0.3f);//to set alpha 

            ((TextView) tab.getCustomView()).setTextSize(11);
            ((TextView) tab.getCustomView()).setText("DeSelected");
            Log.d("TabBar", "unselected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Log.d("TabBar", "reselected");
        }
    });
```

to set tab as default selected then use this statement

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select(); //this is used to set tab as default
```

Answer (score 0):

Kevin answer is great! (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34047188/7699617). Relying on this answer I create realization for apply any changes for `TextView` in `Kotlin`:

```
private fun applyForTextView(parent: ViewGroup, func: (TextView) -> Unit) {
    for (i in 0 until parent.childCount) {
        when (val child = parent.getChildAt(i)) {
            is TextView -> func(child)
            is ViewGroup -> applyForTextView(child, func)
        }
    }
}
```

How it use:

```
applyForTextView(tabLayout) { it.isAllCaps = false }
```