# Change the padding of TextView in TabLayout

Tags: android, tabs, material-design, android-tablayout

I want to change the padding on the textview in the TabLayout. I have a tab that's called Subcategories. This is breaking line wrapping into two lines. Is there a way to do this?

There are answers only concerning the old TabHost view, I am using the TabLayout used by Google's Material Design library using android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.

For TabHost: [How to add padding to a tabs label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421564/how-to-add-padding-to-a-tabs-label)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TextView is not padded out, but the layout surrounding the textview is, so change the LinearLayout's padding:

```
int tabIndex = 0;
LinearLayout layout = ((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)mTabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(tabIndex));
layout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```